# Set up two identical USB printers

Tags: 11.04, usb, printing

I want to hook up 2 USB label printers to one machine, so that each one can have different size labels loaded in it. They are both Zebra 2844 printers. Either one installs and works just fine by itself, but it doesn't recognize that there are 2 of them if 2 are plugged in.

The add printer window just shows one, and if I install one, then go to add the second one, the add printer window still just shows one, and if I select it and set it up (while assuming I'm setting up the second one) it just prints to the first one still.

If I have both of them plugged in, and unplug the one it *doesn't* print to, the printer window shows the one that *does* work as offline.

What can I do to make this work? Is there some way to manually set up the second printer?

Comment: You will probably have to create some udev rules for your printers - see this question and answer for an example of how to separate two USB devices - http://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters-using-udev-rules

Comment: @fossfreedom you should put that as an answer to this question

Comment: @cas - this is an area I dont have much experience with - hopefully someone more knowledgeable can help-out with this.

Answer (score 2):

You must be looking for **Printer classes** (No, not school)

Firstly disconnect both the printers.

Open "Printing" and you will be presented with such a window:
[image]

Press the Plus and select Class:
[image]

Create a new class:
[image]

Add the right printer to this class:
[image]

Repeat this process again for the other printer, If you have done this correctly you will get two new printers in your window, like this:
[image]

With one and two being the new classes. You will now me able to print to both the printers.