# How to distinguish between identical USB's

Tags: 14.04, usb, python, udev, lsusb

I have this system where I have 8 USB RFID readers which I would like to distinguish from one another. Here's a snippet from `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 05fe:1010 Chic Technology Corp. Optical Wireless
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 05fe:1010 Chic Technology Corp. Optical Wireless
```

As you can see both the `idVendor` and the `idProduct` is the same for the two USB RFID readers.

**Q1: Can anyone help me do a** `--attrubute-walk` **with the** `udev info` **so I can see if there's any parameter that is unique to the individual readers. (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)**

This is the sys path I think I'm supposed to look in, and what the folder contains:

```
nicolai@nicolai-K53SV:~$ ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/
1-0:1.0  1-1:1.0  1-1.2:1.0  1-1.4      2-0:1.0  2-1:1.0  4-0:1.0  usb2  usb4
1-1      1-1.2    1-1.2:1.1  1-1.4:1.0  2-1      3-0:1.0  usb1     usb3
```

So of course I tried the following:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4
```

But I can't seem to find the two devices listed at the top (with ID 05fe:1010).

**Q2: If there is a parameter that is unique to the individual reader, how can I (hopefully in python) distinguish between them?**

Here's some python code which I thought I could use (until I realised that the ID's where the same for every RFID reader)

```
import usb

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x05fe,idProduct=0x1010)
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')
else:
    print('Device found')
```

### Update

**A1:** Here's the output from the `lsusb -v`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7818192/

As it can be seen the iSerial is just zero and all the other attributes are the same for both devices.

**So for Q2:** I was wondering if I could use the `setserial` bash command to write a serial to the USB RFID reader. If so, is this serial stored even after the power is lost, or do you have to create a script that creates the serials every time you boot?

Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Does `lsusb -v` show a serial number? Probably called `iSerial`.

Comment: No unfortunately. Here's the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7818192/

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [How to distinguish between identical USB-to-serial adapters?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters?rq=1) - the answer is that you will need to use the USB device path to identify devices.