# How do I use two USB printers?

Tags: usb, printing, udev

I have two USB printers, both of which have different device and product ID's:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 222a:0037
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0493:8760 MAG Technology Co., Ltd
```

When I try map them in the printer set up, they are both recognised with the URI

```
usb://Unknown/Printer
```

The second printer (0493:8760) also allows me map to :

```
usb://Unknown/Printer?serial=Zijiang
```

but it does not require the serial entry on the end. To add a complication, only the second printer maps to lp0, the first does not.

Both printers can print successfully when separately connected but I need to specify which to print to while both are connected.

Does anyone know how I can name these printers, whether through udev rules or other means.

This answer is helpful [How to distinguish between identical USB-to-serial adapters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters) but I was unable to map the udev rules, possibly related to the Unknown printer status.

Answer (score 1):

After much investigation, it turned out that both printers I was using were parallel to USB converted. The printers themselves have a USB port each on them but internally, it seems, there was a converter used.

To solve this, I bought a different printer model as the second printer.