# Distinguishing between two similar usb devices

Tags: usb, udev

This is asked many a times before, but I haven't found any workable solution for my case. In my case, I have got two FTDI based USB <-> Serial converters from which I could not find any distinguishing feature to include in udev rules that I intend to write in order to identify them with a persistent name. The outputs of:

`udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0`

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="USB <-> Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="21"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="90mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0400"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="11"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB <-> Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="383"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.0-32-generic xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{irq}=="40"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{enabled}=="1"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3977"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

and same when done for ttyUSB1:

`udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB1`

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/ttyUSB1':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb-serial"
    DRIVER=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTR{port_number}=="0"
    ATTR{latency_timer}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="USB <-> Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2':
    KERNELS=="3-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="22"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="90mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0400"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="11"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB <-> Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="383"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.0-32-generic xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{irq}=="40"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{enabled}=="1"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3977"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

I tried implementing the first solution @ [How to distinguish between identical USB-to-serial adapters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters) by assigning `KERNELS=="3-1"` to ttyUSB0 and `KERNELS=="3-2"` to ttyUSB1, but it is not persistent and changes everytime I re-connect the devices. Moreover `ATTRS{devnum}` also keeps changing everytime, but it can be noted that they are always in sequence. So, can I use them to fix device names? I am not sure that same device will always be initialized with smaller or larger devnum.

Another option that I tried after following [How to lock device id's to port addresses?](https://superuser.com/questions/536478/how-to-lock-device-ids-to-port-addresses/536648#536648), and did:

`udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0`

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
N: ttyUSB0
S: serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_USB__-__Serial-if00-port0
S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-port0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_USB__-__Serial-if00-port0 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-port0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyUSB0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL=USB__-__Serial
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20\x3c-\x3e\x20Serial
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6001
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0400
E: ID_SERIAL=FTDI_USB__-__Serial
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=ftdi_sio
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=FTDI
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=FTDI
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0403
E: MAJOR=188
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=8719192
```

and then:

`udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB1`

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1
N: ttyUSB1
S: serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_USB__-__Serial-if00-port0
S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-port0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_USB__-__Serial-if00-port0 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-port0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyUSB1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL=USB__-__Serial
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20\x3c-\x3e\x20Serial
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6001
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0400
E: ID_SERIAL=FTDI_USB__-__Serial
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=ftdi_sio
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=FTDI
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=FTDI
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0403
E: MAJOR=188
E: MINOR=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=79099407
```

and then wrote udev rule in the file as 44-my-devices.rules located at /etc/udev/rules.d/:
`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0", SYMLINK+="ttyUSBMotor1"`

`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0", SYMLINK+="ttyUSBMotor2"`

I also copied it to /lib/udev/rules.d/
and then reloaded the rules as:

`sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

`sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart`

But nothing did happen. I think I am making some mistake here, as this should work. The hardware associated always remains the same, and the rule must work. I have tried restarting the pc as well, but to no effect.

Comment: You could perhaps write a script that detects when they are connected and assigns them a name...

Comment: But what should be the identification parameter? As I want to address the devices/ports in a C program, so there is a need to have a persistent name and for that a differentiating param. Moreover, there is no sequence as to when they would be connected. Writing such a script to assign names upon connection would also leave them to have different names at different times.

Comment: It appears that this line: `S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-port0` differs from `S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-port0`.  You could use that to differentiate, assuming it doesn't change.

Comment: Yes @Daniel, did somewhat the same thing by adding `ENV{ID_PATH}` for both of them in udev rules, as I have updated in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using the physical path to the port is working for me, as I would keep the devices connected all the times, so attaching a device with a particular port and using this to identify one of two same devices is good approach to have.
One thing to be noted is that, I had to rename my udev rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d to `my-devices.rules` from `44-my-devices.rules` as pointed out in the `README` file as:

```
If the ordering of files in this directory are not important to you,
it's recommended that you simply name your files "descriptive-name.rules"
such that they are processed AFTER all numbered rules in both this
directory and /lib/udev/rules.d and thus override anything set there.
```

This seems to have worked for me, and I am able to duplicate the ports with user-understandable persistent names.

```
$ ls /dev/ttyUSB*
/dev/ttyUSB0  /dev/ttyUSB1  /dev/ttyUSBMotor1  /dev/ttyUSBMotor2
```

Hope it would help someone else like me.