# Use udev to rename devices with same properties

Tags: 14.04, usb, udev, gamepad, joystick

I have two types of gamepad that have the same udev properties.  One is a USB NES controller and the other is a USB SNES controller.  The udev info is identical for both of them.

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input18/js2
N: input/js2
S: input/by-id/usb-0079_USB_Gamepad-joystick
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:0e:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-joystick
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-0079_USB_Gamepad-joystick /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:0e:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-joystick
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/js2
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input18/js2
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_0e_00_0-usb-0_1_1_0
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
E: ID_MODEL=USB_Gamepad
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Gamepad\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0011
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:0e:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_0e_00_0-usb-0_1_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0106
E: ID_SERIAL=0079_USB_Gamepad
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=0079
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=0079
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0079
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=2
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: TAGS=:seat:uaccess:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=738808992
```

The application uses the ID_MODEL value to identify the controller and assign a button map.  I have several gamepads that do the same thing but am keeping it to 2 for this example.

How would I get udev to either rename or alias ifferent devices that have the same info?  What would that rule look like?

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input32/js2':
    KERNEL=="js2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input32':
    KERNELS=="input32"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="USB Gamepad "
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:0e:00.0-1/input0"
    ATTRS{uniq}==""
    ATTRS{properties}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0079"
    ATTRS{speed}=="1.5"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="15"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0106"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="13"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0011"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB Gamepad "

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:0e:00.0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="241"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.0-74-generic xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:0e:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:0e:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{irq}=="18"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,000000ff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x0194"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1033"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x21cf"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1c.6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="pcieport"
    ATTRS{irq}=="18"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,000000ff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1c1c"
    ATTRS{enable}=="2"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x21cf"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: Is this the complete output of yr `udevadm info ...` command ?  An expanded output, extending to the parent hierarchy would be useful. Can you please edit yr post with that added info ?

Comment: I added the attribute-walk with parent devices.

Comment: If you have a solution of yr own, please post and mark it as the answer with a green check mark. If not, let me know with a comment starting with @Cbhihe how the cookie crumbles. We'll take it from there.

Comment: @beepbeep , welcome to Ask Ubuntu,  There no way to distinguish between two identical (clone) device. However, you posted only output from single joystick (js2) . Could plug both joysticks, get outputs for both and update the question. let us see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen that vendor_id, product_id AND serial_nbr are all identical for different physical devices. To check look up yr `/var/log/messages` after plugging in your devices, one by one to be able to differentiate them in the better case where some difference in id will crop up between them.

**A)** If, in addition to product's id and vendor's id, serial numbers are  also identical across devices, read up [here](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) (as pointed out by @ChrisObrian in a previous [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters)). His answer is identical in principle to that provided by @Grumbel in this thread. This would also probably make yr post a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters). In any case, searching the devpath upwards for a matching device name, yr udev rule can be:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="input", ATTRS{name}=="USB Gamepad ", KERNELS=="input[0-9]*", SYMLINK+="gamepad_Z"
```

**B)** In case serial numbers are not identical, you'd have the following simple udev rule (one per device):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0079", ATTRS{idProduct}=="XXXX", ATTRS{serial}=="YYYYYY", SYMLINK+="gamepad_Z"
```

where you will have to fill in XXXX and YYYYYY with proper values from output from `udevadmin info ...` or from `/var/log/messages` when devices are plugged in.

**NOTE:** In both cases above, you choose Z arbitrarily. Yr devices will show up as `/dev/gamepad_Z`  pointing always to the same physical devices.

Comment: The product id, vendor id and serial numbers are identical.  The link you provided in part A may be helpful.  I need to review, test and update once I get a result.  The KERNELS name is coming up with "input33" and "input34" so it is making a distinction even if I connect them to the same port.  I may be able to work with that.

Comment: @beepbeep: answer update to reflect yr new info. See A). I could not try this on my systems because I do not have similar gamepads handy. HTH.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck.  I need to correct my previous comment.  The kernel is automatically incrementing the KERNELS value by one each time I connect the device.  If I connect/disconnect/connect the same device it increments the input## name.  I did a diff on the attribute-walk for both devices and they only differ by that increment.  In general this doesn't help and the counter resets after reboot.

Comment: @beepbeep: Please do update yr post with that last info on KERNELS being incremented upon each successive mount with no intervening reboot. <<- This will benefit future readers. See my updated answer's udev rule (case A).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't tell the devices apart by other means you can always use the USB path via `ID_PATH`, as that is the name of the actual USB port the device is connected to. You then just have to plug the device always into the same USB port.

Comment: Correct.  and far from ideal, as you well noted: OP would really have to stick to the same USB ports not to render his/her udev rule completely ineffectual.

Comment: In this case there will only be 4 USB ports accessible and I'll be using the path to identify players 1-4.  Player 1 may use any kind of gamepad and so on.